# Which information do I need to extract data from OneDrive via Microsoft's Graph API?

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, extract, onedrive

I want to connect to the Microsofts Graph API to extract some data from OneDrive.

My question is: **What information do I need to do so?** 
I definitely need an API key, but which permissions, etc.?

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample query to get user`s oneDrive data:

```
/users/{idOrUserPrincipalName}/drive
```

Requred permission are Files.Read.All(reading), Files.ReadWrite.All(read/write)
You need to register endpoint in AzureAD, see howto:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2?view=graph-rest-1.0
```